# JQuery not recognizing movement in HTML Input type range

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to update a text field based on HTML5's range slider. This is the first time I am using the range type and I am having trouble understanding what's going on.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>
$('#chanceSlider').on('change', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
});

$('#chance').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#chanceSlider').val($('#chance').val());
});
</script>

          </head>
  <body>

<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">

<input type="range" id="chanceSlider" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" step="0.01" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">




  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I am using. It will eventually get integrated into another page, but this doesn't work for me. I have looked up examples of using this and came up with this code. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work and I do not have a good enough understanding of JQuery to understand why. If you could show me how to fix and/or give me an explanation on why it does not work, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn't work? I put your code in jsfiddle and I see the input text changing when moving the slider.

Comment: you can go demo.chatcoder.com/slider.html I just uploaded and it doesn't work on there. Maybe it has something to with not having the JQuery file correct, but I checked developer tools and the jquery file is there..

Comment: try to move your script fragment to the end of body or wrap it inside $().ready(...) - the elements are not available in header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap you jquery code inside the document ready function because at the time the javascript is parsed, the html elements don't exist yet.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#chanceSlider').on('change', function(){
        $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
    });

    $('#chance').on('keyup', function(){
        $('#chanceSlider').val($('#chance').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Or you do $(function() {...});